# ionic framework, load a javaScript after template is rendered

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a newbie into cross platform development. I am using [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/). I have a log in page once after successful log in another template is rendered. In that new rendered template I want to execute my piece of JavaScript code (a manual pure JavaScript code function). How can I achieve this?

Content of *index.html* (in the *www* directory):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="mysource/calendar.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp"></body>
</html>
```

Template (from ionic template directory):

```
<form>
  <input type="text" value="" readonly onfocus="settoday()">
</form>
```

Content of *calendar.js*:

```
var date = new Date();
var today = date.getMonth();
function settoday(){
  return today;
}
```

The above program is a sample for my JavaScript function to load once a particular template is rendered after a log-in form template.

How can I achieve this on load of a template?

Comment: do you want it strictly `onfocus`? if not then you can easily bind `$scope.today=date.getMonth()` and then set value =today in input field.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jQuery for achieving this.

```
<input type="text" value="" id="calender" readonly />
```

And your JS, which can be added inside the template/your.html itself:

```
$("#calender").click(function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

You can call your settoday() function instead of alerting.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jbcvd2c/) for you to test it.

Non-jquery version: http://jsfiddle.net/6jbcvd2c/1/

Comment: no, my question was not that. i want to call a function which is written in javascript not in jquery, and i want to invoke it on template load in an ionic frmework

Comment: If not in jQuery, you can add an event listener. Check this JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6jbcvd2c/1/

Add the javascript in the template itself, it must work.

Comment: i want to auto load without any event. other than onload in a body tag and window .load option i want a function to get executed. i am talking about in a iuonic framework. if u have not understood my question, m specifically asking in ionic framework

Comment: I do know you want it for Ionic and all of my solutions were compatible with Ionic/Cordova apps. And if I understand you right, you want to show the calender as soon as the form loads, right? http://jsfiddle.net/6jbcvd2c/3/

I guess this is what you want? Just add that code to your template, call whichever function's to be called and make sure you are importing your calender.js in the index.html.

Comment: Thank you bro u r a life saver, i couldn't understand at first what u were telling me, now i got it. thank you for the grate help. :)